# Problem occurs when check conditions in map function React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get data from the backend and display the data in the frontend. To do that I tried this code.

```
function Posts() {

    const [notes, getNotes] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        getAllNotes();
    }, []);

    const getAllNotes = async () => {
        await axios.get(`/buyerPosts`)
            .then ((response)=>{
                const allNotes=response.data.existingPosts;
                getNotes(allNotes);
            })
            .catch(error=>console.error(`Error: ${error}`));
    }
    console.log(notes);

    const buyerId=(localStorage.getItem("userId"));
    console.log(buyerId);

    const [offers, getOffers] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        getAllOffers();
    }, []);

    const getAllOffers = async () => {
        await axios.get(`/viewPendingSellerOffers`)
            .then ((response)=>{
                const allNotes=response.data.existingOffers;
                getOffers(allNotes);
            })
            .catch(error=>console.error(`Error: ${error}`));
    }
    console.log(offers);

    const wasteItem = offers?.filter(wasteItem => wasteItem.status==='accepted' && wasteItem.buyerId===buyerId && wasteItem.wasteItemsListId==='completePost');
    console.log(wasteItem);

    return(
        <main className="grid-b">
            {notes.map((note,index)=> {
                if(note._id===wasteItem.postId)
                    return (
                    <article>
                        <div className="text-b">
                            <h3>Post ID: {index + 1}</h3>
                            <p>Location: {note.address}</p>
                            <p>Post Type: {note.postType}</p>
                            <p>Address: {note.address}</p>
                            <p>Telephone No: {note.contact}</p>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    );
            })}
        </main>
    );
}

export default Posts;
```

Hare, I call the first API and get a length 7 array of objects. This is an image of this result.

[image: First API call results]

Then I call a second API and get a length 6 array of objects. This is an image of this result.

[image: Second API call results]

Then I try to filter second API call results like this `const wasteItem = offers?.filter(wasteItem => wasteItem.status==='accepted' && wasteItem.buyerId===buyerId && wasteItem.wasteItemsListId==='completePost');` and I get length 2 array of objects as the result of this filter function.

[image: Results of filter function]

Then I try to map the first API call data in a map function. To do that I used this condition `if(note._id===wasteItem.postId)`. But this map function is not working. Maybe it does not work because `wasteItem` is an array of objects. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: You should filter your array of notes to check for the ones that have a match in wasteItem array and use map afterwards. Right now your map would return an array filled with undefined and your matches after you fix what Micko suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wasteItem` is an array of objects, but you treated it as object here `if(note._id===wasteItem.postId)`. You would need to iterate through `wasteItem` array first, or use `find()`.

```
{notes.map((note,index)=> {
                if(wasteItem.find(o=>o.postId === note._id) !== undefined)
                    return (
                    <article>
                        ...
                    </article>
                    );
            })}
```